# Could not find schema information for the element 'setting' VS 2015 ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

When building my web app, I get the following message (amongst 77 others, all similar, just for different elements in my web.config)

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'setting' VS 2015 ASP.Net
```

I have looked at the schema for the config,

[image]

looks Ok to me?

I have also other weird stuff going on, like When I add a new webpage, I get an HRESULT FAIL COM error. Ditto with trying to install NuGet packages.

This only started happening yesterday, on a large solution. I had reference errors after a merge, which I have now fixed. All projects target the same  .NET version (4.5).

I have no build errors and everything works, except my recent work - a page that uses partials (worked fine until yesterday!). My colleagues are beginning to doubt me!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: ahhh. Deleting the 'bin' folder seems to have cleared the messages! Back to solving the other weird stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the 'bin' folder, then rebuilding seems to have cleared the messages.